# What is overhead percentage?

Tags: caching, computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

> Consider a 2KB direct mapped cache with blocks of size 1 word. As
>   always, addresses are 32 bits.
>
> How many blocks does the cache contain?  2^7
>
> How many bits long is each tag? (Tags are shown in pink in the class
>   notes.) 2^23
>
> How many bits long is each cache index? (These are green in the notes)
>   2^7
>
> What is the total size of the cache? (32 + 1+ 23) x 2^7
>
> What percentage of the total size is the overhead?

what is .. overhead .. and percentage of overhead.. ?

Answer (score 1):

overhead is tag size, and any other bits the cache needs to store other than the data itself.

(e.g. for an associative cache with LRU replacement, it would need to store some bits that record the LRU state to track which member of the set is next in line for eviction.)

overhead percentage is obviously overhead / total size, as the assignment says.  (not overhead / data).

Comment: So.. in this case, is this (32 + 1+ 23) x 2^7 overhead size..  or (1+23)x 2^7 ?

Comment: If (32 + 1+ 23) x 2^7 is overhead size, how can I find total size..?